# I am not a pleasant sight

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is round and mostly white
>   My suffix is found in mines
>   My infix is to say "right"
>   I usually am an ugly sight

**What/Who am I?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sorry to insult you, but you are:

> An **EYESORE**

*My prefix is round and mostly white*

> **EYE** - an eyeball is spherical (round) and predominantly white in colour (except the pupil and iris).

*My suffix is found in mines*

> **ORE** - what you extract from the earth in a mine, often containing metals and useful elements to be used in industry and manufacturing up on the surface.

*My infix is to say "right"*

> **YES** - something one says to mean 'indeed' or 'right'.

*I usually am an ugly sight*

> An **EYESORE** is something that is particularly ugly to behold (e.g. a building that seems to dominate its surroundings).

Comment: Well done! :D I'll hand you the green mark after this gets a few more views.